# Can we create object to an existing argument array dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arrayobject

For example if i have a code like this

```
var contacts = [{firstName: "Bob",lastName: "Jones",phoneNumber: "6507777777",email: "bob.jones@example.com"}, {firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Johnson", phoneNumber: "6508888888", email: "mary.johnson@example.com"}];
```

Can I do this to add new objects to my array objects?

```
contacts[0].zipcode = 12345
```

and

```
contacts[1].zipcode = 12346
```

Compiler is running succesfully sometimes, but throwing error sometimes saying "object error"

Is it legal to do this way? or is there any other way to add the objects to array?

Comment: yes, that is perfectly fine. Can you set up a http://fiddle.net to show us an example of the error?

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger to see the value of `contacts` when you get the object error. Maybe you have a fencepost error with the array index.

Answer (score 0):

That works. But without more code it's hard to discern what would be causing the error to sometimes happen. You could do a check prior to setting the zipcode to see if your error goes away:

```
if(typeof contacts === 'object' && contacts[0] && typeof contacts[0] === 'object'){
    contacts[0].zipcode = 12345;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new object with that syntax, you can only add or modify properties in an existing object. So the code needs to be something like:

```
if (!contacts[0]) {
    contacts[0] = {}; // initialize the array element
}
contacts[0].zipcode = 12345;
```